# AngularJS - $resource is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to get a grasp of Angular's ngResource. I've started with a simple code excerpt taken from Angular's documentation:

```
angular.module("app", ['ngResource'])
var user = $resource("/REST/user/:id", {userID:'@id'});
```

But when the code is run I check the JS console and I see an error saying:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $resource is not defined

Yes, I've included the 'angular-resource.js' script. I think I'm omitting something obvious, but I can't deduce what it is. Please help!

Comment: Could you point to the part of the documentation from where you got this?

Comment: @Sprottenwels http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource

Comment: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource here, quick search on google. `app` must be your app name, btw.

Comment: please provide a jsfiddle, at least all your sources ... html and js

Comment: You are only including the resource module in your app module. But you don't have a controller or service as far as I can see. You need to have one of those, and inject resource in them.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As suggested in the comments you need to create a controller or service that uses the $resource.

[Here is an example](http://plnkr.co/edit/TFEm9R?p=preview)

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngResource']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $resource) {
  var dataService = $resource('http://run.plnkr.co/5NYWROuqUDQOGcKq/test.json');
  $scope.data = dataService.get();
});
```

Comment: That did the job. Strange that the requirement for controller scope is not mentioned in the documentation (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource) - perhaps it's too obvious to mention - but now I know. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I think it is one of those things that are two obvious to mention.. unless of course you have only just started using angular in which case it really should say!

Answer (score 2):

FYI incase it helps anyone, I had this which wasn't working.
The `$resource` initialization was just returning undefined null, no resource service object.

```
myConstrollers.controller('ConsumerListController',['$scope', '$http','$resource','ConsumerService',function($scope, $http,$resource, ConsumerService) {
    $scope.consumers=ConsumerService.query();
  }]);
```

There was no error.  It turns out for some reason you cannot use `$resource` and `$http` I guess.  Once I removed the `$http`, which was in there because of me using that lower level api earlier, it started working.  Very weird.